# fullscreen no scrolling in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, fullscreen

Modern Chrome supports scrolling on elements that are set to fullscreen mode but this is not the case for elements in Firefox. Does anyone know a CSS trick to get scrolling to work in Firefox? I tried many things like this to get scrolling on elements (in this case the body) if the element does not fit the screen in fullscreen mode.

When using this code below, open up the dev tools and make it take up like 75% of the screen to make the fullscreen element not fit on the screen.

```js
function enterFullscreen(element) {
  if (element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  }

  else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }

  else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  }

  else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

function exitFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  }

  else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  }

  else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  }

  else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  padding: 40px;
}

div {
  padding: 100px;

  background-color: red;
}

div div {
  background-color: blue;
}

body:fullscreen {
  overflow: scroll !important;
}
body:-ms-fullscreen {
  overflow: scroll !important;
}
body:-webkit-full-screen {
  overflow: scroll !important;
}
body:-moz-full-screen {
  overflow: scroll !important;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="enterFullscreen(document.body);">Enter Fullscreen (BODY)</button>

<div>
  <button onclick="enterFullscreen(document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0]);"> EnterFullscreen (DIV 0)</button>

  <div>
    <button onclick="enterFullscreen(document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[1]);"> EnterFullscreen (DIV 1)</button>
    <button onclick="exitFullscreen()">Exit Fullscreen</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Firefox for whatever reason (could be a bug) were if the body element is set to fullscreen, it will not enable scrolling even if the body height is greater than the window. This is not the case for any other DIV element in Firefox. A solution is to have everything inside one DIV tag and have that one DIV tag be inside the BODY tag.

```
<style>

button {
  padding: 40px;
}

div {
  background-color: red;
}

div div {
    height: 200%;

  background-color: blue;
}



:fullscreen {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
:-ms-fullscreen {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
:-webkit-full-screen {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
:-moz-full-screen {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

</style>



<div>
    <button onclick="enterFullscreen(document.getElementsByTagName('DIV')[0]);">Enter Fullscreen</button>
    <button onclick="exitFullscreen()">Exit Fullscreen</button>

    <div>

    </div>
</div>



<script>

function enterFullscreen(element) {
  if (element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  }

  else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }

  else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  }

  else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

function exitFullscreen() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  }

  else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  }

  else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  }

  else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  }
}


</script>
```